# get whitespace back from value that is raw url encoded?

Tags: php, url-encoding

Here i have a value  which have a white space.I passed the value using `rawurlencode()`.But when i want to use the value in sql in database query ,i can't escape the `"%20"` which is added instead of white space

```
<a href =<?php echo "www.example.com?val =".rawurlencode("al zami") ;>click</a>
```

In backend i used `$_GET['val']` ..but it has something like `"al%20zami"` .How to escape them in `$_GET` variable

Comment: The encoding is used to reduce the character set to allowed characters. As part of the request values, the escape sequences are automatically converted back. Besides, there is such a thing like [rawurldecode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

Comment: You have a space before the `=` sign in your URL. Why would you need one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code. here **urldecode** decodes any %## encoding in the given string.

```
echo urldecode($_GET['val']);
```

[Ref: php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're a bit confused with your terminology here, as the `%20` is already escaped. What you seem to be asking, as far as I understand your question, is how to *unescape* it.

For that question the [PHP manual for `rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) holds the answer. Just remember to read the entire page, and read it carefully.

That being said. The fact that you get URL-escaped values inside your `$_GET` array, seems to indicate that you might have some additional problems in your code.
Normally the escaped values are automatically translated by the server when it receives them from the client, and as such manually unescaping them should never be necessary in most cases.

So please post an complete example of your code, which highlights the problem from start to to end. If you do that, we can help you find and fix the true problem. Not just the symptoms.

Comment: actually i am using codeigniter. It didn't automatically unescape the data.i don't have any idea why ? So, I had to come up with a simple example to express my problem

Comment: The unescaping happens before any framework, or any other PHP code, is involved. So this should not have any bearing on the result. However, what it might be doing is double-escaping your output, so that it looks like it's not unescaping it upon receipt.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with the code. Fix the useless spaces, add the quotes around your attribute, and close the PHP tag.

```
<a href="<?php echo "?val=".rawurlencode("al zami"); ?>">click</a>
<?php echo $_GET['val']; ?>
```